# compute $ \mbox{prox}_{t f}(y) = \arg\min_{x} \frac{1}{2t}\|x-y\|^2 + \delta_{\mathbb{B}_{\infty}}(x)$

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I need to compute $$  \mbox{prox}_{t f}(y) = \arg\min_{x} \frac{1}{2t}\|x-y\|^2 + \delta_{\mathbb{B}_{\infty}}(x)\\ 
\text{where } \mathbb{B}_\infty = [-1,1]^n$$

$\delta$ is convex characteristic function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(convex_analysis)

Edit:

My line of thinking : $x$ needs to get closer to $y$ but stay in $\mathbb{B}_\infty $

Comment: Can you clarify your definition of $\delta$? Is it the [convex characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(convex_analysis)) which is zero inside $B_\infty$ and infinity elsewhere?

Comment: The indicator of a convex set is not a convex function (plot it for an interval in the reals and draw some lines - btw no way could be it convex, but its not even concave). You should probably check the definition being used: your program certainly looks like a projection of $y$ onto the unit box. If so, then the convex characteristic angryavian mentions is used to impose this hard constraint, and probably this is intended (note that this is just $-\log \mathbf{1}_A$). If its really the indicator that's intended, then there's no convexity, so no uniqueness of minima is guaranteed.

Comment: What is the norm you are using above?

Comment: I presume that this is the convex indicator function, as mentioned by @angryavian. It would be very unusual to have the 'ordinary' indicator function in the above context,

Comment: My bad - it is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(convex_analysis)

Comment: @ copper.hat - L2 norm

Comment: Then the minimizer is the projection of $y$ onto $B_\infty$ (i.e. the point in $B_\infty$ closest to $y$). This can be achieved by clipping each component to the intervals $[-1, 1]$.